# Online database for Android mobile app and Windows pc app

Tags: android, windows, qt, firebase-realtime-database

I need to have an android app that can read and write to an online database, and a windows pc app that can do the same. Basically I want to view/modify a set of data from the database from both my mobile and pc. 
I considered using firebase as the online database for my android app, but I don't know if can query the data from my windows pc, if say I am using Qt to program a windows app. 
Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even it's a broad question a quick answer would be **yes**, you can query the data from your Windows pc. There is an interesting articole written a few moths ago named [Firebase Database REST API for QT](http://piersshepperson.co.uk/programming/2017/06/26/firebase-database-rest-api-qt/).

Take a look a this post for a better understanding.

Comment: can I access firebase realtime database in my pc Qt app with this API ? sorry the document seemed bit confusing to me!

Comment: Also firebase seem to be meant for Android iOS and web apps, is there any other way by which we can access the same data from my phone and pc. Companies seem to do it all the time, they have an app for mobile and a pc app too that can access their data ! was wondering if it was possible ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. What can i say is that i recomand you Firebase.